# Best terminology to use for forms

Tags: buttons, terminology

The title might not make much sense. But I am creating an admin portal where there will be some dyslexic users.

I have created a few pages that follow the same format. Main page with table and a page to add a new thing or edit the thing.

My question is what terminology to use? So for the create I have 'Create', 'Add', 'New', 'New [name]'. Then in the form for the submit button, should I then do 'Submit' or if the button is 'Create' should the button be the same?

I think for the Edit button it can be Edit and then the submitting button would be 'Update'.

I am also using Font Awesome to add icons to the buttons.

What are peoples suggestions? I am sorry if this seems confusing or not the best place to ask this.

Comment: Would you happen to have any mockups or screenshots of these in context? That would help us to visualize what you're talking about a bit easier.

Comment: What are they creating or submitting?

Answer (score 1):

Focus on font selection, font color, background color, and easily identifiable icons.

"Many dyslexic people find that the readability of a piece of text varies greatly depending upon the font (type face or type style) used."

Per Wikipedia -> "There is some evidence that the use of specially-tailored fonts may help with dyslexia.[1] These fonts, which include Dyslexie, OpenDyslexic, and Lexia Readable, were created based on the idea that many of the letters of the Latin alphabet are visually similar and may, therefore, confuse people with dyslexia. Dyslexie and OpenDyslexic both put emphasis on making each letter more distinctive in order to be more easily identified.[105] The benefits, however, might simply be due to the added spacing between words.[106]"

Sources:

Good Fonts for Dyslexia http://dyslexiahelp.umich.edu/sites/default/files/good_fonts_for_dyslexia_study.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyslexia

https://www.dyslexic.com/fonts/

Answer (score 0):

My background is mostly in Product Management, so I don't have any hard-and-fast rules for you to follow, but my advice would be to use your gut and then put it in front of users and make sure it's clear to them.

In my past experience when looking to optimize sign-ups and membership conversion on websites, copy changes can certainly improve clarity, but it's incremental.  I think your admin users will have better context too as to how they expect the messaging in the portal to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Go with your best guess on the button copy. I would stick with common convention.

Then, iterate based on feedback from users and possibly A/B tests.